# Data changing between functions

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

After looking at what I could find, a few culprits that i've looked at would be the return being unrolled into a simple String, or other data being in the pipe.

My problem is cmdlets run against the data in the 1st function, do not work on the data by the time it reaches the 2nd function.

```
function Get-FileInput() {
    $fileData = Import-Csv $filePath -Delimiter "`t"
    if ($fileData | Get-Member | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "DistinguishedName" -or $_.name -eq "dn" -or $_.name -eq "name"})
    {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Confirmed.
        Processing"$fileData.Count"objects."
        $invalidFilePath = $false
        $fileData
        }
    $data = Get-FileInput
    Write-Host $data
}

$data = Get-FileInput
Set-MultipleComputersEnabledStatus -data $data
```

Everything works fine up until this point. Before it gets passed into the 2nd function, it can be used with Format-Table and and Get-Member and everything appears perfectly fine. Inside Set-MultipleComputersEnabledStatus however, I can't perform the exact same checks on the $data object that I had done inside Get-FileInput

It is looking for a property named "DistinguishedName" which it finds in the 1st function, but won't recognize in the data by the time it gets to the 2nd function.

```
if ($filterType -eq "DistinguishedName" -and $data | Get-Member | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'DistinguishedName'})
{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Valid filters. Processing list."
}
```

I assume this means that after being passed in as an argument to the 2nd function, PowerShell changed the data for me somehow, but I can't find anything documenting what it did, or how to prevent it/work around it.

Comment: Try `if ($filterType -eq "DistinguishedName" -and ($data | Get-Member | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'DistinguishedName'})) { }`

Comment: That would do it. Got so tangled up in the bits I read about PowerShell stringifying function returns I completely overlooked brackets...

Thanks for the quick tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use brackets around the embedded command part so that it is executed first and then the result can be evaluated:

```
if ($filterType -eq "DistinguishedName" -and ($data | Get-Member | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'DistinguishedName'})) { }
```